# C program stores function parameters from $rbp+4 in memory? My check failed

Tags: linux, function, parameters, gdb, rbp

I was trying to learn how to use rbp/ebp to visit function parameters and local variables on ubuntu1604, 64bit. I've got a simply c file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
  printf("hello\n");
  return argc;
}
```

I compiled it with:

> gcc -g my.c

Then debug it with argument parameters:

> gdb --args my 01 02

Here I know the "argc" should be 3, so I tried to check:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400535: file ret.c, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/a/cpp/my 01 02

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffde98) at ret.c:5
5     printf("hello\n");
(gdb) x $rbp+4
0x7fffffffddb4: 0x00000000
(gdb) x $rbp+8
0x7fffffffddb8: 0xf7a2e830
(gdb) x/1xw $rbp+8
0x7fffffffddb8: 0xf7a2e830
(gdb) x/1xw $rbp+4
0x7fffffffddb4: 0x00000000
(gdb) x/1xw $rbp
0x7fffffffddb0: 0x00400550
```

I don't find any clue that a dword of "3" is saved in any of bytes in $rbp+xBytes. Did I get anything wrong in my understanding or commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was trying to learn how to use rbp/ebp to visit function parameters and local variables

The `x86_64` [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) does *not* use stack to pass parameters; they are passed in *registers*. Because of that, you wouldn't find them at any offset off `$rbp` (this is different from `ix86` calling convention).

To find the parameters, you'll need to look at the `$rdi` and `$rsi` regusters:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe3a8) at my.c:4
4     printf("hello\n");

(gdb) p/x $rdi
$1 = 0x3                   # matches argc
(gdb) p/x $rsi
$2 = 0x7fffffffe3a8        # matches argv
```

> `x $rbp+4`

You *almost certainly* wouldn't find anything useful at `$rbp+4`, because it is *usually* incremented or decremented by 8, in order to store the entire 64-bit value.

Comment: Thanks, then how to visit these 2 parameters through $rsi?

Comment: @HindForsum Exactly as shown above: the first parameter is in `$rdi`, the second in `$rsi`.